# GKE Autopilot Ingress Timeout for Requests

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, connection-timeout

I have deployed a simple autopilot gke cluster. In it created an httpbin deployment as below;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  labels:
    app: httpbin
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: httpbin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpbin
        image: kennethreitz/httpbin
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80 
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /status/200
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 25
          periodSeconds: 5
```

Created a service for this deployment.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: httpbin
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

And then created an Ingress type of object.

```
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "ilb-httpbin"
  namespace: "default"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: "httpbin-service"
      port:
        name: http
```

When I try accessing to the service via it's domain-name/IP I am able to get back a response. **This request sent from a POD (netshoot)**

```
bash-5.2# curl http://httpbin-service/status/200 -k -v
.....
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
....
```

If I try to access to the same service via Ingress, which it generates an Internal Load Balancer etc.. again from **the netshoot pod in the same cluster** it's timing out.

```
bash-5.2# curl http://10.132.0.45/status/200 -k -v
*   Trying 10.132.0.45:80...
* Connected to 10.132.0.45 (10.132.0.45) port 80 (#0)
> GET /status/200 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.132.0.45
> User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
< content-length: 24
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Wed, 04 Jan 2023 15:24:16 GMT
< via: 1.1 google
<
```

I just can not find why this is happening. What could it be missing here. I believe it is related to the load balancer to service accessibility. Because, I can see that the last curl is able to connect to the LB frontend but unable to call the target on the LB side.

edit: as per the comment from Yvan below, deployed service yaml (from the GUI)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    cloud.google.com/neg-status: '{"network_endpoint_groups":{"80":"k8s1-c8f531c9-default-httpbin-service-80-748977ee"},"zones":["europe-west1-b","europe-west1-c","europe-west1-d"]}'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"httpbin-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":"http"}],"selector":{"app":"httpbin"},"type":"ClusterIP"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-01-04T10:48:04Z"

...
```

These are the backends in the ingress-generated internal load balancers
[image: neg's in load balancer]

Comment: May I clarify if your httpbin deployment is just a folder in your image? Regarding this concern from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#requirements) one of the requirements for ILB is Network Endpoint Group which I think is lacking in your service yaml.

You can use the same link I shared with you and scroll down to Deploying a Service as a Network Endpoint Group and use annotations:
  cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'. There is also a sample yaml that you can use as a guidance under "to create a service" part.

Comment: Creating the ingress makes all these with above yaml actually makes service deployment with {"ingress" : true}.  I edited the current yaml from service on the GUI. please see edit section at the end of the question

Comment: Where is the netshoot pod you are testing from deployed ? Same cluster and same region or a different cluster/region ?

Comment: the same cluster and same region. my final goal is to get apigee vpc peering up and running. same behavior can be seen, if I set the ilb IP address as target host on apigee proxy setup too.

Comment: fixed the issue with adding a new firewall rule for LB source IP range to kubernetes network tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, my Load Balancer is in a load balancer specific network with specific range. This negates the generic, glb to internal firewall rules and causes access failures.

How to fix;

1. Find cluster network tag on gcloud.
2. add that tag specific firewall rule.